# Powershell Security Groups

Tags: windows, powershell, user-management, automation

Active Directory via powershell want to add users to a specific group. But that is a member of a particular group of users that other members do not want to be included in the relevant group.

For example, a member of the ABC member Group1. Therefore, these members do not want to add to Group2.

As a second example, the ABC member is not a member of Group1. I want to add this member to a member of Group2.

On these variables using Powershell was not able to fully do not know. I would appreciate if you could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try querying the ad groups using powershell, then adding the user to group2 if he isn't a member of group1.

```
$testMember = Get-AdGroupMember Group1 | WHERE{$_.SAMAccountName -ilike 'ABC'}
if (!$testMeber){ Add-Agroupmember -ideneity Group2 -Members ABC}
```

[Add-AdGroupmember](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617210.aspx), [Get-ADGroupmember](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617193.aspx)